# Postgres query with '%%' parameter not returning results via psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

When I execute the below query in a query editor like DBeaver - it returns a result but if I execute the same query via Python & psycopg2 it does not return a result. '%%' should match any title/location so there will always return something. I'm just testing this for a category without keywords but it will also take an array of keywords if they exist depending on the category. So the array could be ['%%'] or ['%boston%', '%cambridge%'] and both should work.

```
select title, link
from internal.jobs 
where (title ilike any(array['%%'])
or location ilike any(array['%%']))
order by "publishDate" desc
limit 1;
```

I've tried adding the E flag at the beginning of the string. E.g. E'%%'

Python:

```
import psycopg2

FILTERS = {
    'AllJobs': [],
    'BostonJobs': ['boston', 'cambridge'],
    'MachineLearningJobs': ['ml', 'machine learning']
}

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """
select title, link
from internal.jobs 
where (title ilike any(array[%s])
or location ilike any(array[%s]))
order by "publishDate" desc
limit 1;
"""

for title, tags in FILTERS.items():
    if not tags:
        formatted_filters = "'%%'" # Will match any record
    else:
        formatted_filters = ','.join([f"'%{keyword}%'" for keyword in tags])

    cur.execute(sql, (formatted_filters))
    results = cur.fetchone()
    print(results)
```

Comment: What is the Python code you're using?

Comment: You've got single quotes, double quotes, and percent signs so I highly suspect your issue is with a character that needs escaping but without seeing the Python code there's no way to know.  [Here's more info](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html?highlight=escape).

Comment: Thanks @AlexW I suspect you're correct and someone may point me in the right direction for escaping % signs / building an array this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Piro for the very useful `cur.mogrify()` clue. That helped me further debug the query to figure out what was going wrong.

I ended up removing the extra set of quotes, I used a named parameter and now it works as expected.

Updated code:

```
import psycopg2

FILTERS = {
    'AllJobs': [],
    'BostonJobs': ['boston', 'cambridge'],
    'MachineLearningJobs': ['ml', 'machine learning']
}

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """
select title, link
from internal.jobs 
where (title ilike any(array[%(filter)s])
or location ilike any(array[%(filter)s]))
order by "publishDate" desc
limit 1;
"""

for title, tags in FILTERS.items():
    if not tags:
        formatted_filters = '%%' # Will match any record
    else:
        formatted_filters = [f'%{keyword}%' for keyword in tags]

    print(cur.mogrify(sql, {'filter': formatted_filters}))
    cur.execute(sql, {'filter': formatted_filters})
    results = cur.fetchone()
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cur.mogrify()` query to look at the SQL finally generated, check in psql if it works, and how you need to tweak it.

Most likely you have to double every `%`.